# Excel Conditional Formatting and Rounding Issues

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to find a way to use excel formatting to show the color red when a specific cell is not equal to another cell. However, there are times when the value is off by two or three numbers due to how excel rounds(ex: 593=594, 593=592).Is there a way to use excel formatting or any other way to make it so if the value of the cell is very close to the targeted cell, it will not result in the cell being formatted to red. Anyway this the simple formula I am working with along with example:

```
=I3<>F3
EX:

**I**    **F**
593       594
```

Essentially the F cell will be highlighted in red but because the difference is negligible,
     I don't want to highlight red. At most, I would like to have a difference of more than 3, where the cell won't highlight red.

Comment: `=ROUND(I3,4)<>ROUND(F3,4)` for example. 2nd argument is digit precision.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the absolute difference between the two numbers. If it is in a given range, which is acceptable, you may consider them equal. Thus, this is the formula that you need:

```
=ABS(I3-F3)>0,5 '0.5 if you are using "." as a decimal separator
```

It will consider 233.4 and 233.6 as similar values. [MSDN ABS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/abs-function)

---

In general, if you write `=ABS(I3-F3)>0,5` in Excel it should evaluate to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If it does not, probably the comma is the problem, thus change the comma with a dot - `.`.

Comment: It did not work. for example for values: 456 and 381

Comment: why did you put 0,5

Comment: @mikerosd - All values with a difference below `0.5` will be considered equal. You may put `0.2` or anything that suits you.

Comment: @mikerosd You may have to put `=ABS(I3-F3)>0.5` instead of `=ABS(I3-F3)>0,5` depending on which version of Excel you have.

Comment: right, but it is not highlighting red when that difference is more, where 456 and 381 are way off

Comment: @mikerosd - first write the formula in Excel and see whether it evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If it gives an error, write the formula as proposed by ImaginaryHuman072889 in the comment above.

Comment: now I'm getting true. but when I put it into excel conditional formatting, nothing happens

Comment: also I can't put 0,5 into regular formula, only conditional formatting works with it

Comment: @mikerosd - so your two comments are exactly the opposite. In general, try to write `0.5`, as far as you are probably using English/American language settings.

Comment: When I want to copy formula for multiple entries, I use applies to: =`$I$3:$K$449`. is that correct